Creating a new slicer in Excel duplicates an existing slicer connected to another pivot chart
I have an Excel file containing many pivot charts with slicers connected to each chart.
I have noticed that when I create a new pivot chart by duplicating an earlier one (ie: by copying an earlier pivot chart and pasting it somewhere new, then just tweaking the PivotChart fields to customise my new pivot chart), any new slicers I create, of the same fields as an existing slicer attached to the earlier and copied chart, becomes an entangled duplicate of that earlier slicer.  They become 'joined at the hip' and begin to control both the old and the new pivot charts together.
Attempting to detach the new slicer from the old pivot chart by going into Report Connections, while it successfully disconnects the new slicer from the old chart, it simultaneously affects the connection settings of the old slicer such that the old slicer no longer controls the chart it was created to control.  The two slicers become joined at the hip and I cannot seem to untangle them!  I cannot untangle them so that the old slicer controls the old chart and the new slicer controls the new chart.
This is clearly because I had created my new pivot chart by copying and pasting.  I am therefore enquiring if there is a connection or other setting somewhere, which I can modify so that the charts and slicers become untangled from each other.
